# NetSuite Saved Search (Bills, PRs, and POs by Vendor Containing Certain Text)

Tags: search, netsuite

New to Netsuite and the saved search function, but I cannot for the life of me get these to show on the saved search together. I can get them to pull separately.

- the PO and BILL record pull from one vendor record containing a certain text
- the PRs pull from another separate field called the proposed supplier containing a certain text

How can I join these three transaction types on one saved search? I'm looking for the documents that contain a certain Text..

[Screenshot of Criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfdzB.jpg)

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post screenshots of what you've already set up so far.

Comment: Thanks. Added the screenshot via a link (can't embed yet). The PO and Bills use the Vendor Fields Name for the name of the vendor and the PR (Purchase Requisition) uses the proposed supplier fields name

Answer (score 2):

PO and Bill are transactions, so you create a search on `transaction` and add filters to specified/required transaction types like Bill and Purchase Order. Although I could't understand what is PR.

And then you can add other search filter on the required field with operator `contains`, which has certain text as you mentioned.